# Using Azure, I have no authorization to enter Microsoft Entra ID (AAD) when using Student Account

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I cannot access into my own `Microsoft Entra ID` and this stop me to see my `client-secret` which is must have for other related authorization.

I read some source to solve this problem:

1. ask for permission
2. try to authorize yourself
3. remove cookies

So far I cannot find any satisfying solution.
I think it only happens with `Student Account Subcription`.
Or is there anything need to do with the different between the gmail of chrome and the account of Azure? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcMc5.png)

I tried my best with

1. This is my account at first, who can I ask for permission? My university IT help desk?
2. I can not access into anything related to Microsoft Entra ID, I think it is AAD before?
3. I tried and it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: Role-based access control manages access to Azure Active Directory and associated resources (RBAC). You will not be able to use Azure Active Directory features if your user account is not assigned with the appropriate permissions.

Roles like Global Administrator, User Administrator, or Directory Reader are required to access Azure Active Directory.

[image]

You must have the "Application Administrator" or "Global Administrator" role in your Azure AD tenant in order to view your client secret. You can administer the applications and see the client secrets for those applications with these roles.

**If still the issue persists**, check the below:

- Check whether you have the access to the Azure subscription that Azure Active Directory instance, if not you will not be able to access AAD.
- Check if there are any organization policy implemented and so you are not able to access AAD.
- Check whether you have required licenses to access the resource.

**Reference:**

[Azure Active Directory Access - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1338463/azure-active-directory-access) by subrothodas-9589